# Readin in stdin to my program returns ��,଄��? What is this

Tags: c, stdin

I'm trying to understand how to fix my code, but it returns a bunch of weird characters. What is this and how can I fix it?

Theres 2 programs involved. The first one reads stdinput and sends the line to another program, which then parses and evaluates each file individually. When the 2nd program attempts to read each file individually it errors out and returns that it cannot read the file "��,଄��"

code to feed in stdinput for first program

```
while (fgets(tmpstring, 1024, stdin) && (tmpstring != NULL)) 
{
    fileName = tmpstring;

    write(report2access[1], fileName, (LINE_MAX* sizeof(char))+1);
    write(negreport2access[1], fileName, (LINE_MAX* sizeof(char))+1);

}
```

code that evalutes each filename in 2nd program

```
while (fgets(tmpstring, 1024, stdin) && (tmpstring != NULL)) 
{
    fileName = tmpstring;

    //remove newline
    if ((pos=strchr(fileName, '\n')) != NULL)
        *pos = '\0';

    token = strtok(fileName, s);

    //walk through tokens
    while(token != NULL){
        access = lastAccess(token);

        if (num > 0){
            if(access > argvseconds){

                printf("%s\n", token); //#DEBUG
            }
        }

        else if (num < 0){
            if (access < argvseconds){
                printf("%s\n", token); //#DEBUG
            }
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed  the most important thing from your post, `tmpstring`'s declaration.

Comment: I declare it as 

char tmpstring[1024];

Comment: so `tmpstring != NULL` is always true. And you need to post the second program.

Comment: the 2nd code snippet is from the 2nd program

should I make it != " " then? Im trying to not let it run when theres no files returned and its just whitespace

Comment: The write statements in the first code are `write(report2access[1], fileName, (LINE_MAX* sizeof(char))+1);` but should be `write(report2access[1], fileName, strlen(fileName)-1);` (or you can drop the `-1` if you want the newline written too).  You're writing a load of junk to the the other program as well as the file name.

Comment: regarding this: '(tmpstring != NULL)) '  tmpstring will never be NULL. as it is always the buffer where the input is to be placed, therefore it will always be the address of that buffer

Comment: this line: 'fileName = tmpstring;' is only copying a pointer.  Hopefully 'fileName' is defined as 'char *fileName = NULL;

Comment: this 'sizeof(char)' is a waste of code space.  because sizeof(char) is defined to always be 1

Comment: assuming that 'LINE_MAX' is some number from a #define;  (LINE_MAX* sizeof(char))+1);. will be writing characters from beyond the end of the input file name.  suggest using statements similar to this: 'write(report2access[1], tmpstring, strlen(tmpstring)+1 );'   and before performing a writes, the code needs to remove any trailing newline from tmpstring.

Comment: there are several details missing from this question, for instance: how are these programs being run?  what is 'negreport2access[1]'? what is 'report2access[1]'?  what is variable 'num'?  what is the contents of string 's'?  what is the function 'lastaccess()' expected to perform?  what is argvseconds?

Comment: Fixed code indentation.

Comment: There's too many unknowns in what you've posted; create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post that, along with the input that generates the unxpected output

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In general, it looks like a filename, followed by a bunch of trash bytes  is being written to `negreport2access[1]` and `report2access[1]` then the second program is trying to parse those trash bytes as if they contained valid filenames.